# Another way of saying "escaping/running away from home"?

Tags: expressions

I know you can say *breaking out from prison*. How about ways of saying escaping/running away from home? Example:

> Speaker A: “What?” I said to Tom on the phone. “What do you mean
>   Mary ran away?”
>
> Speaker B: “Exactly that: she [...] from home.”

Comment: The person asking about Mary is probably not expressing misunderstanding, but rather disbelief. And if he actually didn't understand, it would not make sense to follow up the blunt, straightforward "ran away from home" with some less concrete idiom. Had it been the other way around, I could see it making sense:  "She flew the coop." "What do you mean, she flew the coop?".  "I mean she ran away from home."

Comment: "Exactly that: she *makes bad decisions and will suffer for a very long time unless she returns and seeks shelter* from home."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mary ran away.

**Why?**

The context behind her "running away from home" is quite important.
A few choices......

1-If she ran away from confinement
=> **[got away](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+away)**

2-If she ran away with her beloved
=> **[elope](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=elope%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=)**

3-If she ran away, as if in a panic
=> **[skedaddle](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=skedaddle%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=)**

4- **[fled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flee)**; **[took to her heels](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=take%20to%20one%27s%20heels%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=)**; etc.

(TFD/Google)

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the following.   She has gone missing.

Comment: It would be good if you made it clearer what you mean.